# 3.0 above android version for scrollable swipe tabs, how to add different screen for different tab

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe, android-fragmentactivity, scrollable

I am a beginner to android applications,I working around tab+swipe application, 
my main class is like belove. please help me out.
    public class MainScreenViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private static String list_display_data1 = "item@sec1";
    private static String list_display_data2 = "item@sec2";
    private static String list_display_data3 = "item@sec3";
    private static View rootView;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen_view);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        /*mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                // When swiping between pages, select the
                // corresponding tab.
                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });*/

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_main_screen_view_dummy, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

            dummyTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if(dummyTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                ListView sessionList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.session_list);
                initListView(getActivity(), sessionList, list_display_data1, 30, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            }
            else{
                Log.d("", "");   
            }

            //ListView sessionList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.session_list);
            //initListView(getActivity(), sessionList, list_display_data1, 30, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static void initListView(Context context, ListView listView,String prefix, int numItems, int layout ){

        // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
        String[] arr = new String[numItems];
        for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){

            arr[i] = prefix + (i +1);
        }

        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layout, arr));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                Context context = view.getContext();

                String msg = "item[" + position + "]= " + parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(context, msg, 1000).show();
                System.out.println(msg);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

in onCreateView of dummySectionFragment how to add different list view. I just able to work on visibility of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Add `Fragments` to your `viewpager` for different page for different Tabs.